# Error 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 1: invalid start byte' decoding bytes after decrypting with pycryptodome

Tags: python, encryption, decoding, pycrypto, pycryptodome

My problem is that when I use pycryptodome for decrypting a string in Python 3.6 with the following code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = "133BBB3212332231"
key_bytestring = key.encode("utf-8")
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key_bytestring, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
encrypted_string = 'ý\x82iq\x193\x1aÙË\x04Û£¥\x8dbBOW}Vû\x01\x86zÕ¼Ó)áôO\x14'
encrypted_bytes = encrypted_string.encode("utf-8")
decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_bytes)
decrypted_string = decrypted_bytes.decode("utf-8")
print(decrypted_string )
```

Python throws this error:
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 1: invalid start byte**

In this line:

```
decrypted_string = decrypted_bytes.decode("utf-8")
```

I'm updating some code from Python 2.7, and pycrypto has changed to pycryptdodome. In python 2.7 this works like a charm with pycrypto(I've invented the key so the string is not decrypted well but Python don't throw any error):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = "133BBB3212332231"
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
encrypted_string = 'ý\x82iq\x193\x1aÙË\x04Û£¥\x8dbBOW}Vû\x01\x86zÕ¼Ó)áôO\x14'
decrypted_string = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_string)
print(decrypted_string)
```

How can I fix this? I'm quite desperate, since I've been trying it for a long time and I did't come to anything. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm getting byte 0xc0 instead of 0xbf. What is the output of the Python 2.7 version?

Comment: You changed the key and expect the result of decrypting a string to be valid utf-8? If you encrypt something, the output will be binary data, so having it in the form of an "encrypted string" doesn't make much sense. How exactly did you produce this string?

Comment: This was just an example, because in the real project I receive data in real time. I edited the question with the real KEY and a real encrypted message received, so the key and the data corresponds. Sorry, I thought that an example would be enough to explain the problem

Comment: Receive from where? How? How did it end up in your code? You probably copied that string from somewhere... What is the result in python2 (`repr(decrypted_string)`)? The string you start with contains non-ascii characters, so its actual content depends on the file encoding.

Answer (score 2):

First you should know how Python 3 treats strings differently than in Python 2.

In Python 2, `""` is a byte array, but in Python 3 it's a unicode string. Both `cipher.encrypt` and `cipher.decrypt` expect byte arrays.

So even though in both pieces of code, the *type* of your parameter is fine. Your problem in Python 3 is with calling `str.encode`. It's pretty easy to see that it indeed caused a change by looking at the string length:

```
>>> len(encrypted_string)
10
>>> len(encrypted_string.encode('utf-8'))
14
```

The solution:

First of all notice that in Python 2:

```
>>> "¨vóîÄdX|@9" == '\xc2\xa8v\xc3\xb3\xc3\xae\xc3\x84dX|@9'
True
```

In Python 3, you need to mark your string with the binary prefix (`b""`), your new definition should use: `encrypted_bytes = b'\xc2\xa8v\xc3\xb3\xc3\xae\xc3\x84dX|@9'`

Thus your solution should be:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = "18945BKJVO9W834G"
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
encrypted_bytes = b'\xc2\xa8v\xc3\xb3\xc3\xae\xc3\x84dX|@9'
decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_bytes)
print(decrypted_bytes)
```

Comment: In my real project I receive data in real time in one variable. How can I do this if my string is in one variable?. I've edited my question with the real KEY and a real message received to clarify the problem

Comment: You need to propagate the transition from `str` to `bytes` back to where you receive the message from. For example, if it's from a file, use `rb` instead of `r`.
Remember, you can only encrypt/decrypt byte arrays, not textual strings.

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random

key = "18945BKJVO9W834G"
key_bytestring = key
iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
cipher = AES.new(key_bytestring, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
encrypted_string = "¨vóîÄdX|@9"
encrypted_bytes = encrypted_string 
decrypted_bytes = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_bytes)
decrypted_string = decrypted_bytes
print(repr(decrypted_string))
```

Short description : `Byte` and `String` got same pattern, does not require any correction. Consider how the system is perceived if you do any encoding operation.Cryptographic logic is a byte-based function, which is not very important to which encoding system you are using.  If the input/output or output/input is important to you why do you change the encoding setting of the characters?
**Computers cannot read and write!**

Comment: If I do that, I got this error: **TypeError: Only byte strings can be passed to C code** when I pass encrypted_bytes to decrypt function. I've edited my question with the real KEY and a real message received to clarify the problem

Comment: You don't undestand my description, key is not important on **same script**  ! Your question maybe : `How to protect data on any encode/decode operation ?` **source[Base64] >> target[base64]** if generator and resolver script not same script, got  a lot encoding/decoding  problems.